# In ListView item: TextView containing long words messes up layout

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-constraintlayout

Here is how the list card looks in Android Studio's Design view, so far so good:

[image]

Here is how it looks on mobile. Note the overlapping of the divider and detail text in the second list card:

[image]

What's strange is that the FIRST list card is fine in the mobile view. It also has a very long textview, except the text content is broken up with whitespace.

But the SECOND list card is all messed up and the only difference is the textview content is one long word.

One more exception: having a super long unbroken word in the bottom textview is OK as long as the title textview is short / broken up:

[image]

What is going on here? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the layout xml file for the list card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/reportListItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/unreadMarker"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/dangerousMarker"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="wwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unreadMarker"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unread"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dangerousMarker"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_dangerous" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText"
        tools:text="74 Jeramie Wall Suite 277"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/dangerousMarker"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/locationText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationText"
        tools:text="01:18 PM"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/locationText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/locationText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_small" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/timeMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/timeText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/timeText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/timeText"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock_small" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorDivider"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
        tools:text="I was jhots. No screams be careful. too many details to explain come with me if you want to live take this gun the terminator is co\n\n\n\n\nming" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do not use wrap content. Either define a set height, or scale the height using weights proportionally.

Comment: Hi, do not use wrap content for which elements? I'm trying to have the height scale based on the content, so a set height won't do. Scaling the height using weights also won't do because I have no guarantee the different text contents will maintain some fixed ratio.

Comment: set width not zero or wrap_content for example 50dp

Comment: I need it to work for different screen sizes so a constant width won't work; the textview rectangle should stretch to fit that space with margins

Comment: @Alex then update your layout to use RelativeLayout parent so that you can position your view below the wrap content view.